# Track history of ManyToMany Relationship table with extra fields

Tags: postgresql, database-design

I have a many to many relationship table (named UserLabel) in the postgres db with some extra field. I want to be able to track the history of changes to this many to many table. I came up with the following structure. I'd like to know if there's any **better** way of implementing it

User

1. id

Label

1. id

UserLabel

1. id
2. user_id
3. label_id
4. label_info (jsonb)
5. is_deleted (true or false)

UserLabel can contain more than one record with same user_id and label_id but with different label_info. At any point of time, if I want to query for all the labels for a given user I can do that using this table. Now, updates could occur on this table on **label_id** or **label_info** or **is_deleted** fields. I want to be able to know at any given point of time, what were the labels and label info of a user. For this, I'm using the below table.

UserLabelEvent

1. id
2. user_label_id
3. user_id
4. label_id
5. label_info
6. change_type (value will be one of (create, update, delete))
7. created_timestamp

If I want to check the user labels for any user at any time, I just have to query on user_id and created_timestamp and order the records by created_timestamp and loop over the records to construct the user labels at any given time.

The problems in my current approach:

1. By default, anyone seeing at the schema of UserLabel table feels like there cannot be more than one record with same user_id and same label_id.
2. By looking at the UserLabelEvent, it's not obvious to understand how that table is working.
3. I need to do some post processing to find out the user labels at any given time. By post processing, I mean, loop over the query results and construct the user labels.

Please do suggest any other problems you find with this approach. I will update the post with new inputs.

Comment: What is the question? I see no obvious problem with your setup.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe, Thanks for going through my questions. I updated the question with what I feel are the problems in that approach